# CRecordset - get auto-generated ID after Update()

Tags: c++, mfc, odbc

Having just called Update() on an MFC CRecordset (ODBC/Dynaset) what can I do to pull the auto-generated ID without hitting the database again? Ideally whatever it is would work in both SQL Server and MS Access (so querying for the last identity might not work...)

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done. It's necessary to hit the database a second time to pull the @@Identity. Bummer.